# Greenhouse/ growing question?

Tags: discussion

I tried asking this question on the gardening SE, but didn't receive any good results. I am not sure if this counts as cross posting, since I am asking a bit more in depth, so that is why I posted it here.

I was wondering if anyone had some factual sources on growing plants in greenhouses for someone with a decent undergrad background in biology. Googling just gets me alot of videos that try and "sell me stuff" with the speakers opinion and not alot of explaination behind it. I would like something I could potentially reference to help me do undergrad research in the greenhouse at my school. Specifically, I was hoping for info on growing microgreens.

Comment: Do you want to ask the actual question or discuss whether such a question would be on-topic at BioSE? Since this question is posted in BioSE-Meta I assume the latter, but at the moment it is a bit unclear to me.
For the record, I think such a question could be on-topic, as long as you give some background on what you already know and also restrict the scope to certain aspects of growing (otherwise it would be too broad).

Comment: @fileunderwater.   I would like to ask the acutal question, but I was not sure if it was on topic, so I asked about it here. My background knowledge is very lacking so is the question above too broad or no? Thanks.

Comment: @RoSiv as it stands, the question is off-topic on Biology. Gardeners is definitely the better resource, and if you got a poor reception there I'd recommend you check out their meta site and ask how your question could be improved. The problem is the question is mainly opinion-based, as most recommendation questions are, so the Stack Exchange network may not be the best place to ask at all.